# Custom cursor behavior

Tags: java, html, css

I'm trying to add some custom cursors on my app but every time I receive this error:

```
2012-03-29 14:25:36,013 ERROR org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget - unable to lazily register shared resource img/link1mc.cur
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: img
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1484)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1329)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.DefaultClassResolver.resolveClass(DefaultClassResolver.java:114)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget.respond(SharedResourceRequestTarget.java:151)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.respond(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:105)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1258)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
2012-03-29 14:25:36,013 INFO org.apache.wicket.request.target.resource.SharedResourceRequestTarget - shared resource img/link1mc.cur not found or not allowed access
```

And the cursor path is valid, the cursor is visible on app but in log I always find this error. Other problem is that on IE8 the performance is highly impacted only for two custom added cursors. I'm wondering if I must add .cur extension on mime types?
If anyone have e suggestion please let me know, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So my question would be why are you using java for this you can easily modify your cursor with css, which would be the easiest and best practice as a user can easily disable it if they want.

Check out

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_cursor&preval=url%28smiley.gif%29,url%28myBall.cur%29,auto

Comment: In fact I added that cursor from css but my project is based on java: css looks like: `cursor: url(../img/arrow1mc.cur),default; cursor:url(../img/link1mc.cur),pointer;`

Comment: It's not an answer to this question, as the answer isn't aware of how Wicket makes using URL references in CSS files a real issue. The ../ in the URL above is to remove the class name from the CSS file path that wicket adds. However that then means that the web server is parsing a request for "img/file" and Wicket thinks that the "img" part is a class name. I expect that he is using mountSharedResource("/img/arrow1mc.cur", new ResourceReference(Icons.class, "arrow1mc.cur").getSharedResourceKey()); and finding that it is failing. I can't give an answer, I'm still looking for the solution!